# ajax cache not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery)
>   [The cache option of jQuery .ajax doesn’t work in Firefox and Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084457/the-cache-option-of-jquery-ajax-doesnt-work-in-firefox-and-chrome)

When I click on a page and it loads i want to cache that but right now its not working, if someone can tell me where is the problem in my code and what am i missing. Here is my code:

```
$('.nav ul li a').click( function() {
        var pageHref=$(this).attr('href');

        $.ajax({

            url: pageHref,
            dataType: "html",
            type: "GET",
            cache: true,
            success: function() {

                $('.content').load(pageHref + " #cnt");
            }
         });

        return false;

    });
```

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084457/the-cache-option-of-jquery-ajax-doesnt-work-in-firefox-and-chrome

Comment: i didnt get the idea of cache headers

Comment: FYI `cache` is true by default.